# X58 compatability questions: Xeon and RAM

Tags: memory, cpu, compatibility

I know "hardware compatibility" questions are typically closed as too localized, but hopefully there is some more general merit to these questions.  If not, feel free to direct me elsewhere.

Background: A friend has given me an ASrock X58 Extreme mobo.  I'd like to build a light-duty scientific computing box with it (I'm a math grad student), so I'm thinking Xeon, lots of RAM, and a reliable GPU for CUDA compute.

Questions:

1. It *seems* as though I can install any LGA1366 processor.  Is this false?  Do I have to worry about chipset compatibility?  Specifically, I'm looking at a Xeon E5620 or W3565.
2. From the manufacturer's website, they list the memory compatibility as: "Supports DDR3 2000(OC)/1866(OC)/1600(OC)/1333(OC)/1066."  For maximum stability, should I stick with 1066 RAM, or can I safely install 1600?  Crucial's memory advisor recommended a 4x4GB 1600MhZ kit, so I think I'm guessing I'm okay - will I have to do some BIOS configuration to get it to work correctly?

Thanks ahead!

Comment: Check the online specifications for the motherboard.  That will the best way to get the processor compatability list.  The chipset is handled by the motherboard.  The motherboard only supports a single socket, read the manual, for additional information.  You can install any of the listed memory, you could even in theory, install even faster memory it just would be downclocked.  I don't forsee this question staying open since ALL your questions are answered in the manual.

Comment: @Ramhound the processor compatibility list available in the manual only includes chips that were available at the time of mobo manufacture. I'm essentially asking if a newer CPU such as the E5620 is backwards compatible, which is a question not answered in the man, and I haven't found a good answer elsewhere.

Comment: A newer CPU which is not recognised by the BIOS (X58 firmware usually was BIOS based) is not likely to work with a newer CPU. Which means you want to check the latest BIOS update and see which CPU's it supports.

Comment: As to other CPU's. I got an spare X58 board and looked for a newer CPU (atm it has an i7-920). Good 6 core CPUs are still epxansive, even on sites like ebay. Getting a i7-930 or similar can probably be done cheaply though. Same for reasonable memory (e.g. 32GB).